# Connect with custom user name in Scala/Play using default tools

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

In my Scala/Play application i have to work with database but there's no default user and password because every authenticated application user is bound to different DB user. So i'd like to specify user name and password on obtaining connection, smth like:

```
DB.withConnection(user = "James", password = "secret") { ... }
```

For now i can't find such capabilities in docs (and honestly saying i'm not sure how to specify a search query for my question).

And another question: is it safe to store user password in session taking into account that session is stored on user side? Or are there any best practices for such case when different DB users work with app?

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to Question 1**

In Play, you obtain datasources by name:

```
def getDataSource(name: String): DataSource
```

You'd have to do some heavy hacking of the stuff in package `play.api.db` to get the functionality you require.

That, or you can predefine a bunch of datasources if the number of users of your app is small, and retrieve the connection by their login name, e.g.:

```
db.bob.url="jdbc:h2:mem:db_for_bob"
db.bob.driver=org.h2.Driver

db.alice.url="jdbc:h2:mem:db_for_alice"
db.alice.driver=org.h2.Driver
```

And

```
DB.withConnection("bob") { implicit connection =>
```

Or

```
DB.withConnection(userNameKnownAtRuntime) { implicit connection =>
```

**Answer to Question 2**

Even though the data in sessions are heavily encrypted using the application secret, I would recommend not to store these client-side. Instead, implement something along the lines of **Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant** according to [this section in the OAuth 2 spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-27#section-4.3). That would give your client a token which is only valid for a set period, and could be invalidated server-side if need be.

Comment: Thanks very much! The number of users in database can be quite huge (e.g. 150) and taking into account that play connects all listed data sources during application start - i dont think it would be a nice solution. Moveover if i will edit config after adding/removing every user - i have to recompile the app. So now i think to implement a dynamic connection pool (the number of concurrently working users won't be high) or dynamically add/remove connections to the pool as users login/logout. And thanks for answer to question 2 again!

Comment: Sorry opyate, but even being a helpful advise id's not a solution for my problem yet